# How can I have two serenity.properties files dedicated for two feature files respectively?

Tags: java, serenity-bdd

I have two feature files having each several scenarios.
Both the feature file implementations share some common Java methods, so they both are included inside a single project.
But for some purpose, their serenity.properties files need to be different.

Is there a possibility to markedly assign these serenity.properties files individually for each feature file implementation ?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't currently supported in Serenity.